# How to ignore all text containing special character more than once?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, ksh

Sample Input:

```
apple_ig
rabbit_cat_ig
dog_ig
bird_duck_ig
orange_ig
goat_ig
```

Expected output:

```
apple_ig
dog_ig
orange_ig
goat_ig
```

I need to ignore all data that contains underscore _ more than once in the entire string.

bash, ksh , sed, grep, awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`, to print only lines having maximum one underscore.

```
$ awk -F_ 'NF<=2' file
apple_ig
dog_ig
orange_ig
goat_ig
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ grep -v '_.*_' file
apple_ig
dog_ig
orange_ig
goat_ig
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/^[^_]*_[[:alpha:]]\+$/p' input_file
apple_ig
dog_ig
orange_ig
goat_ig
```

Comment: `sed '/_.*_/d'` would be more straightforward

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use `[[:alpha:]]` in the second instance though, it seems overly restrictive if the idea is to just count the underscores. Similarly, there's no need to require at least one character after the underscore -- and then there's the thing that `\+` is undefined in standard BRE, so that command might not work on all systems. Also that would miss any lines that have no underscores at all. I think you'd have to do something like `sed -n '/^[^_]*\(_[^_]*\)\{0,1\}$/p'` to do that positive match on lines that contain zero or one underscores.

Answer (score 0):

**GNU sed** we try to replace the second occurrence of `_` and breakout on failure`T`, otherwise deleting the pattern space `d`.

```
sed 's/_/&/2;T;d' file
```

**POSIX sed** same as above but inverting the logic, since T command is a GNU add-on::

```
sed -n -e 's/_/&/2;t' -e 'p'file
```

**awk**

```
awk '!/(.*_){2}/' file
```

**Perl** in a scalar / void contexts the `tr` builtin emits a  count of the number of transformations it does.

```
perl -pe '$_=$\ if tr/_// > 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/.*_.*_.*/!p' file.txt
```

output

```
apple_ig
dog_ig
orange_ig
goat_ig
```